# Understanding a piece of code

Tags: vb.net, vb6

I do C#, no experince with VB and I don't have any VB installed. I've been looking at the code below to understand how it works, could someone take a look at this?

So if I call this method with `Cat` and `cat` and don't pass the optional parameter, does it return true and says `Cat` and `cat` are equal?

```
Public Function AreStringsEqual(ByRef sString1 As String, ByRef sString2 As String, Optional ByVal eCompareMethod As VbCompareMethod = vbBinaryCompare) As Boolean

  If LenB(sString1) = LenB(sString2) Then
    If LenB(sString1) = 0 Then
      AreStringsEqual = True
    ElseIf eCompareMethod = vbBinaryCompare Then
      AreStringsEqual = (InStrB(1, sString1, sString2, eCompareMethod) <> 0)
    Else
      AreStringsEqual = (StrComp(sString1, sString2, eCompareMethod) = 0)
    End If
  End If
End Function
```

Comment: This tool is sometimes helpful for doing quick converting to C# (or back to vb.net) which could help in understanding the code: http://www.developerfusion.com/tools/convert/vb-to-csharp/

Comment: @Ihan16 This code is written in VB6 so it cannot be directly converted (in particular, it’s using the functions `LenB` and `InStrB`).

Comment: I'm beginning to wonder if this was really an attempt to create a sort of `StrCompB()` function.

Comment: @KonradRudolph good catch! Maybe I should learn to read :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

That’s some weird code. Anyway, the default for the third argument is `vbBinaryCompare` which means that `"Cat"` and `"cat"` will compare *unequal*. To have them compare equal, you’d need to pass `vbTextCompare`.

Now here’s why the code is weird: it’s utterly redundant. You could just call `StrComp` directly.

Comment: yeah I don't understand how that InStrB is working to say to strings are equal? I guess it wants to check and find second string inside first string ..well then shouldn't it says they are equal if the found location is like zero or one? why is it saying if it is <>0 then they are equal?

Comment: @DarkNightFan Because whoever wrote this code is an idiot. Either they made a mistake (most likely) and have a twisted mind, or they actually *intend* this weird meaning but failed to document it carefully.

Comment: It might be worth noting that a "text" compare is far more complex than simply case-insensitive. There are locale-specific character combinations that can be entirely different yet compare as equal. Example: `StrComp("oe", "œ", vbTextCompare)` returns 0 (equal) for most English locales.

Comment: @Bob While that’s true it doesn’t change the fact that `StrComp` implements full-blown string comparison already, no need for this weird method.

Comment: Yes, but a programmer needs to be aware of it and the O.P. was requesting enlightenment.

Comment: "This is most likely a bug because it would treat these two strings as equal: "foobarbaz" and "bar" (but not the other way round!)." Is completely false. The check would not even run if the passed strings are of different lengths, because of the original `If LenB(sString1) = LenB(sString2)` passing two strings of varying lengths will always return false.

Comment: @DanielCook Ah, true. Hehe. See, the stupid code fooled me. Kind of proves my point.

Comment: @DanielCook: Oh thanks, good catch . So with this method "Cat" and "CAT" will be equal if I don't pass the tihrd optional parameter? ir they will be different?

Comment: @DarkNightFan No, they will *not* be equal – see the answer. Daniel’s commend only concerned my (now removed) statement about what happens when the third argument is provided, when it’s set to `vbTextCompare` and when, furthermore, the strings are of unequal length.

Comment: I would call this function "AreStringsEqualorContained". It will return true with "ohmyGosh" and "oh"

Comment: Just wanted to let you know the likely reason why they didn't call strComp directly. Fool hardy attempt at optimization: I experimented for fun. Doing `InStrB(1, sString1, sString2, vbBinaryCompare)` saves .06-.1 seconds per 10 million iterations over `StrComp(sString1, sString2, vbBinaryCompare)`. The only problem is that all of the saved time is lost due to all the condition checks that are run. And as you said, this could realistically be rewritten as two lines.

Comment: @Y3L1NNa Not with the `LenB` check first.